# why the helpful light bulb only appears on the .js file? How can I active it when editing in .ts file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I code in javascript in vscode and get unknown variable underline in green, I can get the light bulb prompting up, suggesting to add some type definition file. However when coding in typescript, this awesome feature is gone away with just red underline remain. Any idea to get the same light bulb when coding in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code actions ('light bulp') are not yet available when editing TypeScript. Please vote for adding it on [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code)